# Add cumulative (running) totals to TSQL query (SQL Server 2008)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregation

I have the following query that displays weekly totals for a certain date range:

```
declare @from_date datetime
declare @to_date datetime

SET @from_date = '2014-03-30';    
SET @to_date = '2014-08-10';    

SELECT DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) Week,
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) 'From Date',
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) + 6 'End Date',
    COUNT(IDOC.IDOC_ID) 'Total'
FROM IDOC    
INNER JOIN dbo.File_Type FI     
        on IDOC.File_Type_ID = FI.File_Type_ID    
INNER JOIN  IDOC_Team_Assignment ITA    
    ON IDOC.IDOC_ID=ITA.IDOC_ID    
Where IDOC.Import_Date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) 
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date)
```

The output:

```
Week    | From Date      | End Date      | Total
--------------------------------------------------
5965    2014-04-28    2014-05-04        1
5967    2014-05-12    2014-05-18      1
5968    2014-05-19    2014-05-25      2
```

I want to add cumulative total (running total) **Here is what I want accomplish**:

```
 Week    | From Date      | End Date      | Total | Cummulative
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    5965    2014-04-28    2014-05-04        1       1
    5967    2014-05-12    2014-05-18      1         2
    5968    2014-05-19    2014-05-25      2         4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver/10309947#10309947 you want a running total, not a cumulative one.  The link shows you how to do this;

Comment: Doesn't seem straight forward with SQL Server 2008, possible without a temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link xQbert gave you shows you the concept, but it might get a little confusing when you have another *count* already in your *select*.

You need to remove your *group by*, and use *over* on both your *counts*, limiting one to just count over the *group by* you already had, and the second to cover the entire range.

You can't use *rows unbound preceding* in this case since it will create an entry for each row instead of building on the existing result set. But you do need to keep the *order by* in the *over* and at the end of the *select* in sync.

And you also need to add the *distinct* key word.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) Week,
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) 'From Date',
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) + 6 'End Date',
    COUNT(IDOC.IDOC_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date)) 'Total',
    COUNT(IDOC.IDOC_ID) OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date)) 'Running Total'
FROM IDOC    
INNER JOIN dbo.File_Type FI     
        on IDOC.File_Type_ID = FI.File_Type_ID    
INNER JOIN  IDOC_Team_Assignment ITA    
    ON IDOC.IDOC_ID=ITA.IDOC_ID    
WHERE IDOC.Import_Date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date)
```

I can't test this on SQL Server 2008, but I did test it in whatever comes free with VS2013 and I know it works in Oracle. It's worth a shot.

This one was tested on SQL Server 2008 R2 - I hope you aren't in a rush to get this data...

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) Week,
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) 'From Date',
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) + 6 'End Date',
    COUNT(IDOC.IDOC_ID) 'Total',
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(aIDOC.IDOC_ID)
        FROM
            IDOC aIDOC
        INNER JOIN dbo.File_Type aFI     
            ON aIDOC.File_Type_ID = aFI.File_Type_ID    
        INNER JOIN IDOC_Team_Assignment aITA    
            ON aIDOC.IDOC_ID=aITA.IDOC_ID    
        WHERE
            aIDOC.Import_Date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
            AND DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) <= DATEDIFF(week, 0, aIDOC.Import_Date)
    ) 'RunningTotal'
FROM
    IDOC
INNER JOIN dbo.File_Type FI     
    ON IDOC.File_Type_ID = FI.File_Type_ID    
INNER JOIN  IDOC_Team_Assignment ITA    
    ON IDOC.IDOC_ID=ITA.IDOC_ID    
WHERE
    IDOC.Import_Date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) 
ORDER BY
    DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date)
```

And now I changed that to a CTE which looks cleaner in my mind.

```
WITH CTE( WeekNbr, FromDate, EndDate, Total) AS (
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) 'WeekNbr',
        DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) 'FromDate',
        DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date), 0) + 6 'EndDate',
        COUNT(IDOC.IDOC_ID) 'Total'
    FROM
        IDOC
    INNER JOIN dbo.File_Type FI     
        ON IDOC.File_Type_ID = FI.File_Type_ID    
    INNER JOIN  IDOC_Team_Assignment ITA    
        ON IDOC.IDOC_ID=ITA.IDOC_ID    
    WHERE
        IDOC.Import_Date BETWEEN @from_date AND @to_date
    GROUP BY
        DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date) 
)
SELECT
    A.WeekNbr,
    A.FromDate,
    A.EndDate,
    A.Total,
    (SELECT SUM(B.Total) FROM CTE B WHERE B.WeekNbr <= A.WeekNbr) 'RunningTotal'
FROM
    CTE A
ORDER BY
    A.WeekNbr
```

Comment: Thank for giving me this great example. I will need to figure out why its compaining about: COUNT(IDOC.IDOC_ID) OVER (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, IDOC.Import_Date)) 'Running Total'

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: It could be that you can't do this in SQL Server 2008, but Microsoft says it's [okay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Comment: I look at the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx...its not possible in 2008

Comment: Using order by with over, I meant

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the wrong version. You can do it in the newer ones. I'm sorry.

Comment: Try with a partition by 1? I updated the example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54323/discussion-between-bob-and-chaka).

Comment: Bob, you are way too awesome! I wish I give you extra points for this...thank you so much for helping me!!!!!